# Execute a nodejs script in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a Nodejs script which will fetch data from bigquery and populate some of it in a database (running on Google Cloud Platform).
If the script is fetchdata.js, then running it on server from the command line would be node fetch.js
However, I am not sure how to accomplish this with the Google Cloud Platform. 
It seems that I have to deploy this script as a separate service (using Google App engine/ Compute engine) and then call that service externally (using the browser) to execute that piece of code. Am I missing something here?
Earlier I thought this could be accomplished using Google Cloud Functions but even that does not seem to be the correct use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You would need a client to connect to you SQL (database) in order to insert the fetched data and for that you would need to use one of the services **(Google Compute Engine or Google App Engine)**

- In App Engine you can run your [NodeJS script](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart) and then connect the App Engine instance to [Cloud SQL database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) ( if you are using Google Cloud SQL database )
- In Compute Engine, you can run the script and [connect the Compute Engine Virtual Machine to the database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine)